# How do I read MessageBox text using WinAPI

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, messagebox

How do I read a message of standard Win message box (Info)?

Using

```
SendMessage(this.HandleControl, WM_GETTEXT, builder.Capacity, builder);
```

I can only read the header of the message box or the text of the button, but not the message itself.

thanks.

### Notes (from Q&A):

`this.HandleControl` is a handler to the message box window

Spy++ shows no child controls bar the button. That's what it made me thinking that Message Boxes have their own way of keeping text w/out using labels

It's a legacy app written with delphi, the button's class is TButton as per Spy++, but still there's no controls except of button inside the dialog window.

After checking a notepad window, both Image & Text are 'selectable', I guess my app doesn't use a std MessageBox. still, how do I go about extracting the text out of the thing? I can see that no labels in my delphi app can be selected by Spy++ Finder tool.

Comment: Which language are you working in and why are you trying to do that?

Comment: What is `this.HandleControl`?

Comment: I was hoping to get away with a simple lang agnostic API call to get that text. c#/vb.net/c++ will do me anyway.

Comment: @Cody Gray: it's a handler to the message box window.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid you'd say. I don't know what that means. Can we see the *rest* of the code? You're going to need to get the window handle for the *label* control inside of the message box that actually contains the text. You'll probably need to use something like [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494.aspx), if you're not already. Hard to tell how you're getting the handle to the button window.

Comment: @Cody Gray: spy++ shows no child controls bar the button. That's what it made me thinking that Message Boxes have their own way of keeping text w/out using labels.

Comment: What *kind* of a message box are we talking about here? A standard [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505.aspx) kind of message box, as created by the Win32 API? They definitely have a label control that contains the text. The ID of that control has been `0xFFFF` since Windows 95. You should definitely see it with Spy++. Update your question with more details.

Comment: It's a legacy app written with delphi, the button's class is TButton as per Spy++, but still there's no controls except of button inside the dialog window.

Comment: If there's no window handle, then you'll have to screen scrape and OCR it.

Comment: @David: How does Delphi draw message boxes? I assume it doesn't use the API function? OCR really doesn't seem like a good option to me; there should be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: Try simulating a copy operation (Ctrl-C), then fetch the text from the clipboard: messageboxes allow copying the whole content that way (if they're properly done).

Comment: Cody Gray: I'm after checking a notepad window, both Image & Text are 'selectable', I guess my app doesn't use a std MessageBox. still, how do I go about extracting the text out of the thing? I can see that no labels in my delphi app can be selected by Spy++ Finder tool.

Comment: @Cody Well, it depends on which method you use. My Delphi apps use standard message box APIs, task dialog on Vista.  Modern versions of Delphi present wrappers to those APIs. However, there are other legacy Delphi routines that create forms and display the text in non-windowed controls. You'll not get at that text any way other than reading the process memory, hooking the routines or OCR. And I was kind of joking with OCR, it's not really a viable option.

Comment: @Dmitry Can you modify the Delphi app to use MessageBox rather than (and I'm guessing here) Dialogs.MessageBox)?

Comment: Stefan's solution of simulating Ctrl+C is a good idea, but unfortunately, that relies on a little-known feature of the standard `MessageBox` API. If the Delphi app isn't using that, it's *quite* unlikely that whoever implemented its custom message box knew enough or cared enough to throw in that little gem.

Comment: @Stefan: that worked, thanks. I might end up with doing it that way. Ideally we wanted to keep our implementation focus independant, but choosing between a dedicated PC and OCR I'd probably go the first route.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I absolutely can't.

Comment: @Cody @Stefan Delphi's `ShowMessage()` routine does indeed have special handling for CTRL+C.

Comment: I remember having similar issues integrating with an old version of Visual Foxpro. Only the forms were actual Windows windows. Thr sub-controls were painted and handled internally. I think some of the VFP team want on to create Delphi so it figures.

Comment: @Stefan: COuld you propose yuor comment as an answer and I'll mark it off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message text is in a label control on the modal MessageBox dialog window.  You have to get the window handle to the MessageBox dialog (win32 API FindWindow) then retrieve the window handle to the control (win32 API GetDlgItem) and then retrieve the text from that window win32 API GetWindowText).

EDIT --

```
TCHAR text[51] = {0};
HWND msgBox = ::FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("MessageBoxCaption"));
HWND label = ::GetDlgItem(msgBox, 0xFFFF);
::GetWindowText(label, text, sizeof(text)-1);
```

Comment: If you're talking about @Jodrell's msg, he is referring to FoxPro. A standard Windows MessageBox has a window of class type Static which contains the text of the message box. Spy++ will show you this.  Control ID is still 0xFFFF as @Cody mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned this. Could have posted the answer myself, in fact. Unfortunately, it doesn't actually answer this question. The Delphi message box that the app in question is using doesn't actually have a label. Ignore the comment about FoxPro, start at the beginning of the comment exchange.

Comment: @Cody - my bad.  I missed the "Show all 15 comments" -- never saw any mention of Delphi til i did that.  Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I mean, that's your decision. I was just pointing out that this had indeed been suggested, but was unlikely to work. The rapid pile-on of comments certainly doesn't help people to follow the important details of the exchange. That's why it's important to ask a question with all the important details already there, so people don't have to drill them out of you or assume things.

Answer (score 2):

Try simulating a copy operation (Ctrl-C), then fetch the text from the clipboard: messageboxes allow copying the whole content that way (if they're properly done).

The OP commented that: *that worked, thanks. I might end up with doing it that way. Ideally we wanted to keep our implementation focus independant, but choosing between a dedicated PC and OCR I'd probably go the first route.*

Personally I've tested this in Delphi 6 and it comes out looking like this:

```
---------------------------
Confirm
---------------------------
You are about to close the program
WARNING: Are you sure?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

**Note:** This is based on an answer that was proposed by "Stefan" in the comments to the original Question