# Find a window handle by text contained in the window

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which runs on an unattented machine. When this application experiences problems, it pops up a message box (using the same title as the main window) which needs to be dismissed by clicking OK.  What I am trying to do is to identify when the application has popped up the message box and respond accordingly.

I know that AutoIt has a function called WinWait which will let you check for the content (not the title) of the window and get the handle for the window.  Is there a way I can do something similar in C#?

I did have a scan but couldn't find anything about this specifically.  I can already get the window by it's title but need to read the messagebox content to identify the message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GUI window does not contain text, it contains pixels. Some of those pixels might be arranged to appear to a human reader as text, but unless the window exposes an interface to obtain its text, you can't read it without sophisticated OCR. Having said that, most of the common controls do expose such an interface. If the window is composed of labels (static), edit boxes (edit), etc., you can enumerate those child windows and read their text. For example, a standard message box contains a label control that can be read. Note that not all apps use standard controls or dialog boxes.

Here is a solution for reading the label control in a standard message box:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5982827/351385

Answer (score 3):

You need to pInvoke to EnumWindows:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows

You can then iterate through the windows and compare titles.

Update:
Since the controls are also windows, you can iterate through them as well. Thus, you can look for specific label controls that might contain text you're looking for. If you use Spy++, you can determine characteristics of the specific controls you're looking for (such as window class) to help you narrow your search.